# How to use Oracle's Jdbc OCI driver for Direct Path inserts?

Tags: oracle, jdbc, oracle-call-interface

Trying to see if there's a good programmatic way to implement Direct Path inserts using OCI. Has anyone here tried to use the jdbc OCI driver for Direct Path and succeeded? If so, can you please give out the details for doing so?

I see that for oci to work one might have to download the oracle sql client. I just want to be sure that oci driver supports Direct Path inserts via OCI JNI calls before actually trying it out.

Thanks

Comment: What you have asked amounts to a Yes/No question. What is your _actual_ question?

Comment: Question edited. Thanks.